# How to get all messages raised when a statement fails

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, error-handling, error-log

Executing the below query will generate two error messages

```
ALTER TABLE [MFClassProperty] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_MFClassProperty_MFProperty]
```

Error messages are:

> Msg 3728, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 'FK_MFClassProperty_MFProperty' is
>   not a constraint. Msg 3727, Level 16, State 0, Line 3 Could not drop
>   constraint. See previous errors.

If I use a try..catch block, then it shows only the last message.

- Why isn't it moving to the catch block on the first error?
- Is there any way to get all error messages?

This is sample situation.

Comment: TRY CATCH would always return last error message which is encountered.

Comment: then why its not end the process after the first error?

Comment: I dont know the code so cannot comment.

Comment: code attached in the question. While executing that query am getting two error messages

Comment: So what is your question, is it about TRY CATCH or resolving the error mentioned

Comment: I think the problem is that in SQL Server 2008, `SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()` in the `CATCH` block returns only the last error, whereas without the `TRY/CATCH`, SQL Server will display both errors. In 2012+, you are able to use `THROW` in the `TRY/CATCH` block to show both errors.

Comment: I posted an answer to a similar question: [Catching two error messages/Throw into table](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139187/catching-two-error-messages-throw-into-table#149787)

Answer (score 4):

This is expected behavior with `TRY/CATCH` in T-SQL.  The related [Connect bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/746979/try-catch-construct-catches-last-error-only.) report was closed as "won't fix":

You'll need to use a client application (e.g. SQLCMD, PowerShell) to capture all error messages.