# Catching two error messages/Throw into table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, error-handling

My goal is to catch errors from backup jobs into monitoring table.
The problem is, that there are cases that backup statement returns more than one error, so ERROR_MESSAGE() is not enough:

> Msg 3201, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot open backup device '...'
>   Operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
>
> Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 BACKUP DATABASE is terminating
>   abnormally.

I can use throw to catch both messages, but is there an easy way to insert throw output into table or overcome this problem in another way?

Comment: Related: [How to get all messages raised when a statement fails](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/116119)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enhance error handling with Extended Events to overcome the TRY...CATCH shortcoming you are experiencing.  The design pattern involves these steps:

1. Create and start an Extended Events Session: it will capture `sqlserver.error_reported` events, filtered primarily by SPID.
2. Execute a statement in a `TRY` block.
3. Within (or after) the `CATCH` block, read the XEvents session data.
4. Use the available data to respond to the error(s) as appropriate.
5. Stop and drop the XEvents session.

Here's an example that can be run manually in a single batch from SSMS. Just make sure to replace all occurrences of "2016" in the script with your SPID.

```
CREATE EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(2016)]
ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported
(
    ACTION(
        sqlserver.session_id,
        sqlserver.sql_text
    )
    WHERE [package0].[not_equal_unicode_string]([message],N'''''') 
    AND [severity]>(10) 
    AND [sqlserver].[session_id]=(2016)
) 
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
WITH (
    --ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS
    --NO_EVENT_LOSS
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,

    MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=1 SECONDS,
    MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,
    MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,
    STARTUP_STATE=OFF
);

ALTER EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(2016)] ON SERVER STATE=START;

BEGIN TRY
    BACKUP DATABASE master
    TO DISK = 'master.diff.bak'
    WITH DIFFERENTIAL;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @XEData XML

    SELECT @XEData = CAST(xet.target_data AS XML)
    FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xet
    JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xe
        ON (xe.address = xet.event_session_address)
    WHERE xe.name = 'Error Handling Session(2016)';

    /*
    Check value of "totalEventsProcessed" to ensure events have been 
    dispatched to event session target (ring_buffer).
    If no events have been processed, delay for a period of MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY +1 (in seconds).
    */
    IF @XEData.value('(/RingBufferTarget/@totalEventsProcessed)[1]', 'INT') = 0
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';

        SELECT @XEData = CAST(xet.target_data AS XML)
        FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xet
        JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xe
            ON (xe.address = xet.event_session_address)
        WHERE xe.name = 'Error Handling Session(2016)';
    END

    --Comment/uncomment as desired to show the formatted XML session data.
    SELECT @XEData;

    --Shred the XML. Do whatever you want with this data: 
    -- log it to a table, create and send an email alert, etc.
    SELECT 
        x.c.value(N'(@name)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS EventName,
        x.c.value(N'(@timestamp)[1]', N'datetime') AS EventTime,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="error_number"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS ErrorNumber,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="severity"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Severity,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="state"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [State],
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="user_defined"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS UserDefined,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="category"]/text)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Category,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="destination"]/text)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Destination,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="is_intercepted"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS IsIntercepted,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="message"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Message],
        x.c.value(N'(action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS SqlText,
        x.c.value(N'(action[@name="session_id"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS SessionId
    FROM @XEData.nodes('//RingBufferTarget/event') AS x(c)
    --WHERE x.c.value(N'(data[@name="destination"]/text)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') = 'USER'

END CATCH

ALTER EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(2016)] ON SERVER STATE=STOP;
DROP EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(2016)] ON SERVER;
GO
```

After running the script, your SSMS output should look similar to this:
[image]

There's a lot of moving parts there. But you might be able to make it work for you. I wrote a few related blog posts about TRY...CATCH that may be helpful:

[The Unfulfilled Promise of TRY...CATCH](https://www.davemason.me/2016/09/08/the-unfulfilled-promise-of-try...catch)

[Enhanced T-SQL Error Handling With Extended Events](https://www.davemason.me/2016/09/14/enhanced-t-sql-error-handling-with-extended-events)

[Part 2: Enhanced T-SQL Error Handling With Extended Events](https://www.davemason.me/2016/09/19/-part-2:-enhanced-t-sql-error-handling-with-extended-events)

Comment: Nice approach, I've rewrite your query to use dynamic spid, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my anwer, Michael.  BTW, there's a handy & reusable variant of your dynamic query in this blog post: [Part 2: Enhanced T-SQL Error Handling With Extended Events](http://itsalljustelectrons.blogspot.com/2016/09/Enhanced-TSQL-Error-Handling-With-Extended-Events-Part2.html)

Comment: Crazy, isn't there an easier way to handle this? My old error handling method isn't working anymore. My `TRY/CATCH` block is just not working.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is, that there are cases that backup statement returns
>   more than one error, so ERROR_MESSAGE() is not enough.

In the SQL Agent job that you use for backing up your DBs with backup devices, just have each step move onto the next step whether they fail or succeed. However, have the very **last step** have the **below logic** in it and tell it to **report failure on failure and to report success on success**.

This will email you the failure detail from the msdb tables for that job as you'd see in the SQL Agent job history area for the current date records. You could always check the SQL Agent history manually when you get the email notification as well but this works well for the need where I've set it up.

I'm sure you could use the logic and make some changes to suite your need further too. In my case, each backup job to backup device is it's own separate step with each moving onto the next step regardless of the results, and the very last step is as I indicated above and is sufficient for failure monitoring.

If I'm not in the office or by VPN connection, the emailed HTML table data will give me an idea if this needs attention and so on checking Outlook Web Mail.

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10'  ----ten second pause to ensure everything needed is written to table
SELECT  step_name, message
FROM    msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
WHERE   instance_id > COALESCE((SELECT MAX(instance_id) FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory
                                WHERE job_id = $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID)) AND step_id = 0), 0)
        AND job_id = $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))
        AND run_status <> 1 -- success

IF      @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN
        RAISERROR('*** SQL Agent Job Prior Step Failure Occurred ***', 16, 1)

DECLARE @job_name NVARCHAR(256) = (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs WHERE job_id = $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID)))
DECLARE @email_profile NVARCHAR(256) = 'SQLInstance Name Alerts'
DECLARE @emailrecipients NVARCHAR(500) = 'emailaddress@domain.com'
DECLARE @subject NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SQL Server Agent Job Failure Report: ' + @@SERVERNAME
DECLARE @msgbodynontable NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SQL Server Agent Job Failure Report For: "' + @job_name + '"'

--Dump report data to a temp table to be put into XML formatted HTML table to email out
SELECT sjh.[server]
    ,sj.NAME
    ,sjh.step_id
    ,sjh.[message]
    ,sjh.run_date
    ,sjh.run_time
INTO #TempJobFailRpt
FROM msdb..sysjobhistory sjh
INNER JOIN msdb..sysjobs sj ON (sj.job_id = sjh.job_id)
WHERE run_date = convert(INT, convert(VARCHAR(8), getdate(), 112))
    AND run_status != 4 -- Do not show status of 4 meaning in progress steps
    AND run_status != 1 -- Do not show status of 1 meaning success
    AND NAME = @job_name
ORDER BY run_date

IF EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM #TempJobFailRpt
        )
BEGIN

-----Build report to HTML formatted email using FOR XML PATH
DECLARE @tableHTML NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
<html>
<body>
    <H1>' + @msgbodynontable + '</H1>
        <table border="1" style=
        "background-color: #C0C0C0; border-collapse: collapse">
        <caption style="font-weight: bold">
                ****** Below is the SQL Agent history detail from the SQL Agent job named: ''' + @job_name + ''' . ******
        </caption>

<tr>
    <th style="width:25%; text-decoration: underline">SQL Instance</th>
    <th style="text-decoration: underline">Job Name</th>
    <th style="text-decoration: underline">Step</th>
    <th style="text-decoration: underline">Message Text</th>
    <th style="text-decoration: underline">Job Run Date</th>
    <th style="text-decoration: underline">Job Run Time</th>
</tr>' + CAST((
            SELECT td = [server]
                ,''
                ,td = NAME
                ,''
                ,td = step_id
                ,''
                ,td = [message]
                ,''
                ,td = run_date
                ,''
                ,td = run_time
            FROM #TempJobFailRpt a
            ORDER BY run_date
            FOR XML PATH('tr')
                ,TYPE
                ,ELEMENTS XSINIL -- brings back non isnull NULL column values as empty without making HTML table look odd for empty value otherwise
            ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '
    </table>
</body>
</html>';

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = @email_profile
    ,@recipients = @emailrecipients
    ,@subject = @subject
    ,@body = @tableHTML
    ,@body_format = 'HTML'

--Drop Temp table
    DROP TABLE #TempJobFailRpt
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT '*** No Records Generated ***' 
    DROP TABLE #TempJobFailRpt
END
END
```

Comment: Thanks, but emailing failures is not an issue, since we have monitoring system that checks error logs and sends emails, I can check backup history, but usually it prints a lot of info, so sometimes it is not clear what the problem is on failures, dividing each backup to each step probably will help, but it means a lot of maintenance work since we have multiple servers, so I'm looking for simpler solution.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didn't find a solution to this issue, we had a frequent errors on Maintenance log backup plans, I didn't find any useful solution and decided to script them to usual jobs and wanted to catch those errors, but this job just don't fail, so I don't need to implement this logic anymore, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

DMason's query with spid handle:

```
DECLARE @Spid varchar(6)
DECLARE @Sql varchar(max)
SELECT @Spid = @@spid
SET @sql = 
'CREATE EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(' + @spid + ')]
ON SERVER 
ADD EVENT sqlserver.error_reported
(
    ACTION(
        sqlserver.session_id,
        sqlserver.sql_text
    )
    WHERE [package0].[not_equal_unicode_string]([message],N'''''''''''') 
    AND [severity]>(10) 
    AND [sqlserver].[session_id]=(' + @spid + ')
) 
ADD TARGET package0.ring_buffer
WITH (
    --ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS
    --NO_EVENT_LOSS
    EVENT_RETENTION_MODE=ALLOW_SINGLE_EVENT_LOSS,

    MAX_MEMORY=4096 KB,
    MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY=1 SECONDS,
    MAX_EVENT_SIZE=0 KB,
    MEMORY_PARTITION_MODE=NONE,
    TRACK_CAUSALITY=ON,
    STARTUP_STATE=OFF
);

ALTER EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(' + @spid + ')] ON SERVER STATE=START;'
EXEC(@Sql)
BEGIN TRY
    BACKUP DATABASE master
    TO DISK = 'master.diff.bak'
    WITH DIFFERENTIAL;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    DECLARE @XEData XML
    DECLARE @XEName varchar(100) = 'Error Handling Session(' + @spid + ')' 

    SELECT @XEData = CAST(xet.target_data AS XML)
    FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xet
    JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xe
        ON (xe.address = xet.event_session_address)
    WHERE xe.name = @XEName;

    /*
    Check value of "totalEventsProcessed" to ensure events have been 
    dispatched to event session target (ring_buffer).
    If no events have been processed, delay for a period of MAX_DISPATCH_LATENCY +1 (in seconds).
    */
    IF @XEData.value('(/RingBufferTarget/@totalEventsProcessed)[1]', 'INT') = 0
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:02';

        SELECT @XEData = CAST(xet.target_data AS XML)
        FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets AS xet
        JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions AS xe
            ON (xe.address = xet.event_session_address)
        WHERE xe.name = @XEName;
    END

    --Comment/uncomment as desired to show the formatted XML session data.
    SELECT @XEData;

    --Shred the XML. Do whatever you want with this data: 
    -- log it to a table, create and send an email alert, etc.
    SELECT 
        x.c.value(N'(@name)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS EventName,
        x.c.value(N'(@timestamp)[1]', N'datetime') AS EventTime,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="error_number"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS ErrorNumber,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="severity"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Severity,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="state"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [State],
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="user_defined"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS UserDefined,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="category"]/text)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Category,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="destination"]/text)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Destination,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="is_intercepted"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS IsIntercepted,
        x.c.value(N'(data[@name="message"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Message],
        x.c.value(N'(action[@name="sql_text"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS SqlText,
        x.c.value(N'(action[@name="session_id"]/value)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS SessionId
    FROM @XEData.nodes('//RingBufferTarget/event') AS x(c)
    --WHERE x.c.value(N'(data[@name="destination"]/text)[1]', N'NVARCHAR(MAX)') = 'USER'

END CATCH
SET @Sql = 
'ALTER EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(' + @Spid + ')] ON SERVER STATE=STOP;
DROP EVENT SESSION [Error Handling Session(' + @Spid + ')] ON SERVER;'
EXEC(@sql)
GO
```